# Error with jspdf when using grunt uglify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jspdf, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a AngularJS application, in which i use jspdf library. When i run dev version with `grunt serve`, everything is fine. But if i build the app using `grunt build`, using uglify, the minified version has this errors:

```
jsPDF PubSub Error Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined
jsPDF PubSub Error Cannot set property 'pdf' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'pdf' of undefined
```

"grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.11.1"

I found the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/237), but it doesn't help.

Comment: check if there are comments like `//` if they get inlined they comment out the whole block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated `grunt-contrib-uglify` and `grunt-usemin` and it solved the problem for me.